# Inserting current date and time into Access database

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I am trying to insert the current date and time into an Access database, using Delphi.

The procedure I am using is as follows:

```
procedure WriteToDatabase;
  var
    TableName, DateTimeNow : string;
    GetCurrentDateTime : TDateTime;
  begin
    GetCurrentDateTime := Now; // The current date and time to write as the FuncID in the database;
    DateTimeNow := DateTimeToStr(GetCurrentDateTime);
    ShowMessage('The current date and time is: '+DateTimeNow);
    ConvertDateTimeForAccess(DateTimeNow);
    TableName := 'tblFunction';
    frmMain.ADOCommand.Connection := frmMain.ADOConnection;
    frmMain.ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='+
    DatabaseName+';';
    frmMain.ADOCommand.CommandText := 'INSERT INTO '+TableName+ ' VALUES ('+DateTimeNow+ 'y = 3x^2 + 4x + 4);';
    frmMain.ADOCommand.Execute;
  end;
```

Unfortunately I get an error when I run the program, namely, 'Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided'.

Is the issue perhaps the formatting of the date? I did not think this was an issue however as I am entering it into the Database as a string type as opposed to a date.

Can somebody please suggest what needs to be changed here?

Comment: The date / time delimiter in MS Access is #, but I am puzzled, why not just create a default value?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Would you mind explaining how one would go about doing this?

Comment: what's the meaning of `y = 3x^2 + 4x + 4` ? just use parameters.

Comment: That's just the value of FuncExpr in this table in the Database. Although I agree I should change this.

Comment: Modify the table so that any append automatically uses the current date & time (now())

Comment: Okay so I changed the databse creation code to be: 'frmMain.ADOCommand.CommandText := 'ALTER TABLE tblFunction ALTER COLUMN FuncID(40) date()';'

Comment: simply use `INSERT INTO YourTableName(YourDateFieldName, FuncExpr) VALUES(now(), 'y = 3x^2 + 4x + 4')` and really, learn to use parameters.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot :) And yes I shall.