# Adding Date into Access Database with SQL INSERT statement

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-7

I'm having trouble adding a date field into my SQL statement - no syntax error but it saves the date as 1905-06-17 any tips please?

The var is

```
ExpireDate : String;
```

Value

```
ExpireDate := DateToStr(IncYear(Today,1));
```

Statement

```
datamodule1.qryDB1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO table SET Member_ExpireDate = '+ ExpireDate +' WHERE Member_ID = .................';
```

Comment: You need to insert `DateTime` ?

Comment: How hard did you try looking before asking this q?  Google found this easily enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271448/inserting-current-date-and-time-into-access-database

Answer (score 1):

You are using the version of `DateToStr()` that relies on the user's current OS locale settings.  DBs have particular formats that they expect date/time strings to be expressed in, and the OS's locale settings might not match those formats.  You can use the overloaded version of `DateToStr()` that takes a `TFormatSettings` as input so you can specify the exact formatting of the output string (via the `TFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat` member):

```
var
  fmt: TFormatSettings;
  ExpireDate: string;

fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;
fmt.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy-mm-dd';
ExpireDate := DateToStr(IncYear(Today,1), fmt);
```

Also, date/time strings need to be wrapped in quotes in SQL statements.  You can use the `QuotedStr()` function for that purpose.

But more importantly, your `INSERT` statement is malformed anyway.

If you are trying to *add a new record*, it needs to look more like this instead:

```
datamodule1.qryDB1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO table (Member_ID, Member_ExpireDate) VALUES (' + SomeIDValue + ', ' + QuotedStr(ExpireDate) + ')';
```

Otherwise, if you are trying to *modify an existing record*, you need to use an `UPDATE` statement instead:

```
datamodule1.qryDB1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE table SET Member_ExpireDate = ' + QuotedStr(ExpireDate) + ' WHERE Member_ID = ' + SomeIDValue;
```

Either way, it would be best to use a parameterized query instead.  Let the DB itself handle all of the necessary formatting for you:

```
datamodule1.qryDB1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO table (Member_ID, Member_ExpireDate) VALUES (:MemberID, :ExpireDate)';
datamodule1.qryDB1.ParamByName('MemberID').AsInteger := SomeIDValue; // or whatever data type your field uses
datamodule1.qryDB1.ParamByName('ExpireDate').AsDate := IncYear(Today,1);
datamodule1.qryDB1.ExecSQL;
```

```
datamodule1.qryDB1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE table SET Member_ExpireDate = :ExpireDate WHERE Member_ID = :MemberID';
datamodule1.qryDB1.ParamByName('ExpireDate').AsDate := IncYear(Today,1);
datamodule1.qryDB1.ParamByName('MemberID').AsInteger := SomeIDValue; // or whatever data type your field uses
datamodule1.qryDB1.ExecSQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert the date to string. Insert the data as date and use parametrs to minimize the errors. Using parameters the component format the datatime as correct format.

```
var
  ExpireDate : TDate;
begin
  ExpireDate := IncYear(Today,1);
  datamodule1.qryDB1.SQL.Text := 
     'INSERT INTO table SET Member_ExpireDate = :expireDate WHERE Member_ID = ..';
  datamodule1.qryDB1.Params.ParamByName('expireDate').Value := ExpireDate;
```

Depending on the components you use, `ParamByName` may be some different, but all `TQuery` descendant components have this method.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response problem solved... should have used #'+ExpireDate+'# all working great now thanks.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. you need a specific date format besides the `#` prefix/suffix. i.e `'#' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', DT) + '#'` read @Remy's answer for details. Your soltution may fail on other OS using different locale.